# Function search from the files 20.0.0.1 to 20.0.0.21

Tags: powershell

I have 21 files from 20.0.0.0001 to 20.0.0.0021 in my directory D:\Updates3 .
I have a function "search" with 3 parameters: the directory, le first number of my file, the last number of my file
My problem is when I enter the 3 parameters in my function search:
the directory: D:\Updates3
the first number: 20
the las number: 1
I have 3 results
20.0.0.0001
20.0.0.0011
20.0.0.0021

whereas, I want only the result 20.0.0.0001
What is the solution please?

here is my code:

```
$UpdatePath = "D:\Updates3"

function search {
    param (
        [string]$UpdatePath,
        [int]$M,
        [int]$j
    )
    $UpdatePath = "D:\Updates3"
    $Updates = (Get-ChildItem -Path $UpdatePath).BaseName
    
foreach ($item in $Updates) {
   
    if ($item -like "$M.0.0.???$j" ) {
        write-host $item
    }
}

}
search $Updates 20 1
```

Comment: You are dealing with strings. You will have to convert them to actual numbers to be able to use them like you want. You could try to treat them as `[VERSION]` types, This way you could access the single elements as major, minor, build and revision.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to convert them as [version] types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pitty your function doesn't really return anything and only writes to the console the file(s) found.
Why not turn this into a function that actually returns a [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) object you can get all kinds of properties from and if needed use its methods?

Also, try using the Powershell `Verb-Noun` naming convention for functions.

The below code doesn't cast the the basename of each file into a [version] type, but uses regex to both ensure the file's BaseName is in the format you describe, ignoring other files, but also it captures the first and last numbers to compare against:

```
function Find-File {
    param (
        [string]$Path,
        [int]$M,
        [int]$j
    )

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File | 
        Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '^(\d+)\.\d+\.\d+\.(\d+)$'} |
        Where-Object {[int]$matches[1] -eq $M -and [int]$matches[2] -eq $j}
}

# find and (if found) return the file as FileInfo object
$theFile = Find-File "D:\Updates3" 20 1
```

Regex details

```
^            Assert position at the beginning of the string
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d        Match a single digit 0..9
      +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)            
\.           Match the character “.” lterally
\d           Match a single digit 0..9
   +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\.           Match the character “.” literally
\d           Match a single digit 0..9
   +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\.           Match the character “.” literally
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   \d        Match a single digit 0..9
      +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)            
$            Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
$path4 ="D:\Updates3"
function search {
    param (
        [string]$Path,
        [int]$M,
        [int]$j
    )
    
    $Updates = (Get-ChildItem -Path $path4).BaseName
   
  
    $g=foreach ($item in $Updates) {
       [version]$item
       [version]$a="$M.0.0.$j"
       

       if ([version]$item -eq $a) { 

           Write-Host $a
           
       }
      
    }

}

search $path4 20 20

PS D:\powershell> d:\powershell\Untitled-1.ps1
20.0.0.20
```